# Code reflector for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Hi i`m looking for something similar to teleriks just decompile product that is able to take any .net binary/dll and reflect the code behind... the tool does not have to have GUI, just being able to extract the code into the filesystem will be just as good.

now i know there is a project called class-dump, but from what ive seen through using the tool it is only capable of spitting out header files, am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not missing anything about class-dump, it will only output interfaces, since this information is available in the runtime information of any object.

I dont know of any decompiling tool that gives you a high-level language representation of your code, and I doubt it exists.

What you have is disassembling, by means of `otool -tV` or more advanced tools like [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/), which is able to sort of "decorate" your disassembled code.

About teleriks, I don't know anything about it, but I guess that its "decompiling" feature really relay on the fact that C# and VB use bytecode, so this will retain much more information than (machine code + symbols). But please, correct me if I am wrong.